# Where can I find RestKit Post sourcecode or tutorials?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, xcode, json, restkit

I am trying to find some documentation on how to POST to an api with RestKit. I have not been able to find any good tutorial or direction. I can GET json data and display it on an iphone app - but I am trying to figure out how to do the reverse, i.e. POST from ios to an external json api. What resources did you guys learn to do this? The explanations on the git are pretty brief - or am I just not getting it?
Any help would be great! THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's documented on the front page of the RestKit GitHub page: [RestKit : post-patch-and-delete-an-object](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit#post-patch-and-delete-an-object)

Answer (score 0):

In this situation google can help you much better than anyone else.

Some useful links:

- [Rest API](http://www.restapitutorial.com/)
- [Intro to Rest](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13097/intro-to-restkit-tutorial)
- [Beginning Rest](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-beginners-introduction-to-http-and-rest/)

Comment: Thanks- the restapitutorial doesn't talk about it in terms of restkit -and the wenderlich and nettuts don't talk about post reques.I'll keep looiking Thanks though